# Получение экранных координат курсора мыши

Tags: java, listener, координаты, jpanel

Во фрейм добавил JPanel, а в панель добавил 2 лейбла X и Y.

Как вывести координаты мыши в эти лэйблы относительно всего экрана?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо зарегистрировать слушатель перемещения мыши в объекте панели и
воспользоваться методом `MouseEvent.getLocationOnScreen()`:

```java
JLabel labelX = ...;
JLabel labelY = ...;
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        // Получение координат относительно экрана
        Point p = e.getLocationOnScreen();
        labelX.setText( String.valueOf( p.x() ) );
        labelY.setText( String.valueOf( p.y() ) );
    }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое тебе, работает, а вне формы координаты как то можно получить?

Comment: @DCP все можно, только надо четко сформулировать проблему и если не будет получаться, то задать вопрос тут, на SO

Answer (score 0):

```
PointerInfo a = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
Point b = a.getLocation();
int x = (int) b.getX();
int y = (int) b.getY();
System.out.print(y + "jjjjjjjjj");
System.out.print(x);
Robot r = new Robot();
r.mouseMove(x, y - 50);
```

Смотрите здесь:: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439022/get-mouse-position